# Angular+ Component Inheritance - using a subscription in the child

Tags: angular, angular5, subscription, angular-http, angular-httpclient

I'm new to inheritance in Angular 5 but experienced with Http

In a regular component (no inheritance) I have full confidence in subscribing to a http service

I would use the following

```
this._MasterService.getRegular('Theodore/portfoliolist')
.subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.portfolios = data;
  console.log(this.portfolios)
});
```

In a child component (that extends the parent) if i do this it logs no data

```
  ngOnInit()
    { 
      console.log(this.portfolios)
    }
```

Is there a way to store the result in the parent component to an array that can be used without a subscription?

Comment: Your value is being retrieved asychronously so you'll need an asynchronous way of getting the reference to the result of you need to run code when the result comes back. Why don't you just hold onto the observable response instead of subscribing and holding onto the return result?

Comment: OK more than happy to try that recommendation. Would you please able to help?

Answer (score 0):

Since the child extends the parent, it is in fact that child who should be subscribing. So move `this._MasterService.getRegular(...)` to the ngOnInit() of the child component.